# Codeigniter - How to update records?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$this->db->where('user_id', $agent_id);
$result = $this->db->update('users', $update_array);
```

The above codes update the database record when data moved to the update
table in the program such as:

```
$upadte_array['us_address']="54 George street";
```

but, the above codes don't update the database record when the address data captured from 
the form.

In both cases, `print_r($update_array);` shows the data is there, in both cases the $result is equal to 1 that means update was successful.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: please show the $agent_id and $update_array

Comment: how many values you need to update. If u want to update only one value try to use `$this->db->set();`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$update_array = array(
               'us_address' => '54 George street'
            );
$this->db->where('user_id', $agent_id);
$result = $this->db->update('users', $update_array);
```

OR

```
$this->db->update('users', $update_array, "user_id = {$agent_id}");
```

Comment: There is a misunderstanding in here, I mentioned when we move the data in the program ($update_array['us_address']="54 George street") it updates correctly, but when the data captured from the form (monitor) the data will not update the database record. Thanks

Comment: debug and verify the variable before update when data is gonna update from form. what are you doing when you posted the data from form ?

Comment: As a matter of debugging and verifying of the variable. I do print_r($update_array); this shows all the data captured from the form correctly and are in the associated variables, but the database record get updated with blank fields, while when I do $update_array['us_address']="54 George street"; then the database record get updated correctly. It sounds the update query doesn't like the data that captured from the form, but the print_r($update_array); shows all the data correctly in both cases, either from the form or moved into the variable in the program. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Is anyone there to help please: Just give you a hint, this problem occurs only within the Codeigniter environment. I tested the subject out of the Codeigniter environment, MySql works correct and updates the database record in both cases, including when data captured from the form. I believe, We need to concentrate on all the programs & micros related to MySql database inside the codeigniter environment, in summary we have to find out what causes the Codeigniter to have such an impact on MySql. Thanks

Comment: @user1376064 please add the result of print_r($update_array) in question so that i can understand the associative array

Comment: Ok I run the process by entering "16 Pitt Street" on the address field of the from on the monitor, the result of the print_r($update_array); is as follows: Array ( [us_first_name] => [us_address] => 16 Pitt Street [us_address2] => [us_suburb_id] => [us_phn_num] => [us_mobile_num] => [us_fax_num] => [us_state_name] => Dubai [user_id] => 58 )

Comment: Now this is the 2nd run, I add this code in the update program: $update_array['us_address']="56 George Street"; the result of the print_r($update_array); is as follows:     Array ( [us_first_name] => [us_address] => 56 George Street [us_address2] => [us_suburb_id] => [us_phn_num] => [us_mobile_num] => [us_fax_num] => [us_state_name] => Dubai [user_id] => 58 )   In this run the address field of the database record get updated with "16 Pitt Street". Thanks

Comment: in this array the us_address is 56 George Street and it is updated with 16 Pitt Street, right ? where are you verifying these results ?

Comment: I verify the result from the updated database record via phpMyAdmin, us_address field of the record is updated with "56 George Street", as it was moved in the program to the update array, but the us_address field updated with blank as  "16 Pitt Street" data was captured from the form on the monitor. Thanks

Comment: so this is issue of program where you are looking the field value. it is updating the correct result

Comment: Issue of php, codeigniter or MySql database, whatever it is, the  captured value from the form is lost and the database record get updated with blank value. It shouldn't be code issue, as there is no extra codes between the print_r($update_array) and the mysql update codes. So it means it is NOT UPDATING the correct result when the data captured from the from.

Comment: Is there any one to help this please?

Answer (score 0):

Is your code a copy and paste from your source code? Because if so, you have a typo:

```
$upadte_array['us_address']="54 George street";
```

should be

```
$update_array['us_address']="54 George street";
```

Comment: Yes, it may solve the problem. In such times that I doubt the variable name typing, I copy the variable name that I'm sure about its correctness, then try to Find all instances of the variable via editor.

Many times one instance is not highlighted and I delete and paste the var name instead of correcting it.

Comment: You are right there is a typo above in here, but that typo doesn't exist in the program. Please note, when we move the data in the program such as ($update_array['us_address']="54 George street") it updates correctly, but when the data is captured from the from  (the monitor) the value doesn't get updated on the database record.